# Import database into OrientDB by command in Windows 10

Tags: json, cmd, orientdb

I exported a sample database (its Graph is workable) from Orientdb and unzip the .gz file, and then I am trying to build a new project by root and import that sample database I exported. However, errors occurred. Was it my command lines wrong?

I tried to change the path of the database.

C:\orientdb\bin> oetl.bat mydb.json

Expect: successfully import the unzipped JSON file；

Error message: java.langClassCastException:com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record....
[image: error message]

Appreciated for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

cd c:\orientdb-3.0.20\bin
console.bat--- OK
connect remote: 127.0.0.1 :/ mydb root password--- OK
export database mydb.export.gz